# Could someone remind me what this means again? $\nabla U = \pm F$

Tags: energy, newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

You know that for a potential function (conservative force/fields) that

$\nabla U = \pm \vec{F}$

In math, we don't have that minus sign, we have only the plus one.

What does it mean if you get rid of the plus sign? I remember the minus signs tells us that the force is always in the opposite direction of the increasing potential function. Does math tell me there exists a potential function such that it's force also increases as potential goes up?

Comment: I'm curious, where have you seen that equation with $\pm\vec{F}$? I have never seen it with a plus sign.

Comment: pretty much in any calculus book?

Comment: Not just any calculus book, or at least not the ones I've used as far as I remember. If you give a specific reference I can elaborate... but that should be done in [chat].

Comment: OP writes $\vec{\nabla}(\pm U) =\vec{F}$. The whole question seems to be just a sign flip $U\leftrightarrow -U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, it just gives a duality with vector fields and scalar fields in multivariable calculus, associated with *conservative* vector fields and line integrals.  As such, the $\pm$ is irrelevant, because it can be absorbed into the force vector.  For physics, we take the sign convention to be negative, so that it agrees with the fact that the force is *restoring* the object it acts on to a lower energy configuration.  Note that we could alternatively absorb the negative sign into the potential! It is all a matter of sign convention, and when you *define* potential and force in physics (as stated above), the negative sign appears in your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, we can write
$$\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}=\pm\mathrm{d}E,\qquad\mathrm{if}\ \mathbf{F}\equiv\pm\mathbf{\nabla}E.$$
Here $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field, $\mathbf{l}$ is a position vector, and $E$ is a scalar field.

In physics, the work done by a force $\mathbf{F}$ over the infinitesimal displacement $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}$ equals the left-hand side in the above relation. Thus, under the condition as given above, the right-hand side is also true in physics. The scalar field $E$ is called the energy corresponding to the given (conservative) force. When evaluating the above relationship and a minus sign appears, the corresponding energy is called potential energy (as for weight and the restoring force on a spring, for example).

For Newton's second law, $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}=+\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right)$. This is an example of $\mathbf{F}=+\mathbf{\nabla}E$.